# Перемещение по классам Python

Tags: python, ооп

Есть код:

```
class main:
    class sub:
        def function_from_sub():
            # Функция main_function
    def main_function():
        print("Something")
```

Задача - вызвать функцию, относящуюся к функции **main**, не передавая экземпляр класса в **sub** функцию и не создавая новый экземпляр экземпляр класса **main**. Это возможно?

Comment: `@staticmethod`, мне кажется, решит все ваши проблемы

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо в данном случае использовать `@staticmethod` как написал Александр в комментарии.

```py
class Main:
    class Sub:
        @staticmethod
        def function_from_sub():
            Main.main_function()

    @staticmethod
    def main_function():
        print("Something")
```

Вызвать метод:

```py
>>> Main.Sub.function_from_sub()
Something
```